# True or False: I know vaguely why it is false, but not clear enough to reproduce it.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $x_1,x_2\in V$ and $y_1, y_2\in W$ for $V$, $W$ vector spaces, there exists a linear transformation $T : V → W$ such that

$$T(x_1) = y_1\text{ and }T(x_2) = y_2$$

Comment: can you include in your post what are the stuff that you know vaguely?

Comment: If x2 = 2x1, then T(x2) must be 2T(x1) = 2y1. but why can't 2y1= y2?

Comment: It depends on whether $\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $\{y_1,y_2\}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: are you saying that it could be true?

Answer (score 3):

So you have an idea to exhibit a counterexample.

Just let $x_2 = 2x_1$, then we must have $$T(x_2) = 2T(x_1)$$  if the map in the question exists, then we have $$y_2 = 2y_1$$ but this relationship need not hold.

The question is not why can't $2y_1 = y_2$, in fact sometimes it can, but why must it. It is not a statement that holds true for all choice of $x_i, y_i$.